# Management of lot of #include statements and header files

Tags: c++, include, header-files

In my current project. A lot of my `.cpp` and `.h` files have plenty of includes in them such as 6 or 7 of headers declared in the following manner.

```
#ifndef A_Header
#include "a.h"
#endif

#ifndef B_Header
#include "b.h"
#endif
```

I wanted to know would it make sense if I wrapped all of these headers (used in the project) in a single header and then declare that header in each source file as such

```
#ifndef Wrapper_Header 
#include "wrapper.h" /*This would contain a collection of all headers*/
#endif
```

Any suggestions and drawbacks of this plan that I am not anticipating?

Comment: It makes much more sense to put those include guards *inside* the headers so that whatever includes them doesn't have to do extra work.

Comment: don't include the kitchen sink, only include what u need. compile time is already bad with C++.

Comment: @chris how do you put include guards inside the header ?

Comment: My headers already start with `#ifndef B_Header
#define B_Header` ....... `#endif`

Comment: Then why have the check around them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's totally bizarre.

Every header should contain a *header guard*:

```
#ifndef THIS_HEADER
#define THIS_HEADER

/* contents of the header */

#endif
```

This goes *inside* the header, not in the including `.cpp` file. The compiler detects the header guard and avoids re-reading all the text when it's included again. This can save seconds of compilation time.

If your headers have that, then the guards in the `.cpp` file are extraneous and you should remove them. 6 or 7 headers isn't a lot, but that silly boilerplate does sure add up.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So from what I understand is that my header files already have guards and I dont need to worry about guards when adding them in my cpp file. ? Did I understand this correctly

Comment: @Rajeshwar Yep, since the `#ifndef` and `#endif` lines are completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Never wrap your headers, always be explicit, make it clear what is included, and do not include what you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

Potatoswatter is correct

But I like to add use "forward declaration".

I am sure you can google it.